# replace a column of a matrix by consecutive numbers

Tags: r

I have generated a matrix of dimension (5x3). Now I want to replace my 2nd column  with (1 to 3) such as the column values become

```r
[,2]
1 
2
3
1
2
```

I am getting an error message like this:

> Error in hdcell[, 2] <- (1:3) : 
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I am new to R. I know it is a simple question.

Comment: Try `hdcell[,2] <- rep_len(1:3, 5)`.

Comment: To understand why you got the error, and why @MartinGal 's solution worked, read https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html and scroll down to "20.4.3 Scalars and recycling rules"  (Oh, and I'm real glad I bought the book in hardcopy.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make @Martin Gal answer work for any matrix/data frame length with

```
hdcell[, 2] <- rep_len(1:3, nrow(hdcell))
```

Just in case. :)